# How can a function including a sin operation be linearly transformable for any offset?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, linear-transformations, nonlinear-analysis

In the paper ["Attention is all you need"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.03762.pdf) the authors have chosen a function to encode the position of a word in a sequence (section 3.5). The following encoding is chosen:

$ PE(pos, 2dim) = sin(pos / 10000 ^ {2dim/d_{model}} ) $

For the purposes of this question this function can be simplified to:

$ PE(pos) = sin(pos) $

The text states that "for any fixed offset $k$, $PE(pos+k)$ can be represented as a linear function of $PE(pos)$". This did not seem obvious due to me due to the nonlinearity of the sine function. Other resources like [Attention is all you need Explained](http://mlexplained.com/2017/12/29/attention-is-all-you-need-explained/) mention this property but do not go deeper into it.

I attempted to use linear regression techniques in Python to derive this, but  was unable to find a fitting linear transform. As $k$ increases and the sine waves resulting from the $PE(pos)$ function get out of sync, the correlation of the transformation and the truth decreases.

Did I misapprehend the statement in the paper, or is my code or understanding of the underlying math here faulty?

Comment: I think that here, "linear" is to be understood as $O(k)$ (computer science complexity notation), and not in its mathematical meaning (linear algebra...).

Comment: The statement does read to me as making the claim that for every $k$ there exist constants $a$ and $b$ such that
$$\operatorname{PE}(\text{pos}+k)=a\operatorname{PE}(\text{pos})+b.$$
This is indeed false if $k$ is not a multiple of $\pi$, and true otherwise (with $b=0$ and $a=\pm1$).

Comment: @Jean Marie Thank you for your input. I'm having difficulty interpreting the text that way. The text explicitly mentions relative positions can be easily learned by the neural network, which to me indicates that the nature of the transformation is linear in the mathematical sense rather than time-complexity wise. The text also does not shy away from using Big O notation anywhere else in the text, so this omission seems spurious to me.

Comment: @Servaes The inputs for this function are integers, so the cases where your equation are true are rarely applicable in the actual use case. Can I conclude, based on this, that the statement in the paper is functionally incorrect?

Comment: From a quick scan of the paper it seems the authors are rather sloppy in their notation, terminology and methodology throughout the paper. I wouldn't call the statement functionally incorrect, I would call it very unclear. What do they mean by $\operatorname{PL}_{\text{pos}}$? What do they mean by 'a linear function of'? It doesn't speak for them that they chose these functions because they *"hypothesized it would allow the model to easily learn to attend by relative positions..."* without any justification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Upon closer inspection, the article defines the function $\operatorname{PE}$ separately for even and odd dimension as
\begin{eqnarray*}
\operatorname{PE}(\text{pos},2d)
&=&\sin(\text{pos}/c^d),\\
\operatorname{PE}(\text{pos},2d+1)
&=&\cos(\text{pos}/c^d),
\end{eqnarray*}
for some constant $c=10000^{\frac{2}{d_{\text{model}}}}$. The trigonometric identity
$$\sin(\alpha+\beta)=\sin(\alpha)\cos(\beta)+\cos(\alpha)\sin(\beta),$$
then yields the identity
$$\operatorname{PE}(\text{pos}+k,2d)=\operatorname{PE}(\text{pos},2d)\cos(k/c^d)+\operatorname{PE}(\text{pos},2d+1)\sin(k/c^d),$$
which the authers seem to call a linear function of $\operatorname{PE}(\text{pos})$.